# JPM not recognized as a command

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to write my fist firefox addon, but I can't seem to get jpm working. My OS is Windows 7. I have node js installed and I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Installation) to install the add-on sdk. However, after I install jpm and I try running the command, I get the error jpm is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file." below is a screenshot of the command prompt window.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `nodejs` folder's path is `C:/nodejs/`

You can run `jpm` from the command line, but you must do it from `nodejs` installation directory.

If you wish to run it from any directory, what you need to do is edit a `System Variable` called `Path`, by ***appending*** to it the path to your nodejs installation, like this: `;C:\nodejs\`. Afterwards open a new terminal (command prompt) session.

So for example: `go to Control Panel` -> `search for "system variable"` -> `edit system variables` -> `find "Path" system (not user) variable on the list` -> `edit it` -> `append ;C:\nodejs\ to the end of its text` -> `open new command prompt`.

I'm running a Polish version of Windows at the moment, so the guide isn't exact. I'll update it later. By `system variable` I mean `global system environment variable` as opposed to `user environment variable`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem...
when you install `jpm` using the `npm --global` option, the package is installed in `c:\users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\`

In your example, you can either call `jpm` by specifying the complete path.

`C:\users\B^3\AppData\Roaming\npm\jpm`

Or add the `C:\users\B^3\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the environment variable PATH as suggested by @Sagi